# concurrentHashMap.merge(key,1,Integer::sum) : Is this operation threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

concurrentHashMap.merge(key,1,Integer::sum)

Is the above operation thread-safe? What is the best way to make it threadsafe?

Comment: Have you read the docs of this class and speciffically merge method?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)) explicitly says: _"all operations are thread-safe"_

Comment: I have read the comments about the thread safety of the map implementation. I am not sure about the Integer: :sum with the merge method. I have written a test and it gives me inconsistent results. @MichałKrzywański

Answer (score 2):

The operation is *atomic* and hence it is thread-safe, from the docs

> The entire method invocation is performed atomically.  Some attempted
> update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while
> computation is in progress,  so the computation should be short and
> simple, and must not  attempt to update any other mappings of this
> Map.

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentHashMap class is thread-safe

Comment: Just because somebody calls a class "thread safe," that does not always mean that every single thing you can do with instances of the class is thread safe. IMO, the OP's question is a reasonable thing to ask, but I'm not upvoting the question because they should have asked the [Javadoc for ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)) before they asked here.